# Is it allowed to track company details based on GPS location? GDPR

Tags: gps

A customer has asked me to write an application that gathers the GPS location of all visitors of their website, and to find the companies that have visited based on the GPS location. If permission for the GPS location was not granted, then I'd look it up based on the IP address (less accurate, but there are some ways).

e.g. GPS -> Address -> company (in reality this would be a bit more complex)

I'm worried I can get into problems, even though I know that a lot of companies use such technology.
Is this allowed w.r.t. the GDPR laws? Is it ethical?

GDPR applies to all applications that do not use anonymous data. However, this data is not linked to any person, but to companies only. Does the GDPR still apply?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question for lawyers, not programmers.

Comment: Tell your customer about your doubts. You are a programmer, so I would not ask a lawyer (it would take so much time to understand all legal framework and terminology correctly). Note: so you make clear you are not an expert on GDPR (and so customer could not blame you [such kind of customers exist]). Note GPS tracking is asked explicitly by browser, so you may expect unwanted reaction from no-more-potential clients.

Comment: Maybe ask this question in https://law.stackexchange.com/